# What are the abbreviations in the kitchen on this house plan?

Tags: kitchens, layout

My top-floor flat in Scotland was converted from a victorian terraced townhouse in 1967.
I've got part of the plan from the building warrant at the time (but it has the edges cut off, so I can't read the notes in full).
I'm trying to figure out what the kitchen layout would have been when it was converted.

What would the items marked "C", "F", "DC" and "SD" mean?

I was guessing cooker and fridge for the first two but I don't know if there would be a fridge at that time when there is the larder separately. I'm fairly sure the "S" would be the sink.

[image]

Comment: DC might be "dish cabinet/cupboard" I suppose, given its location. In 1967 I'd expect a fridge or freezer. The SD location looks more normal for a sink (or half a sink, with S being the other half - the S location is not in front of the window and uncomfortably close to F for working room. Reaching a bit the deeper of two sink basins side by side, possibly? Hopefully someone with local knowledge of the time will wander by and have an answer, rather than a speculative comment. Note seems to say "hinged flap to window drier unit" from the letters we can see.

Comment: The **F** is probably "fridge" although it seems an odd place for one.